# Site com comportamento instável

Tags: suporte, status-pronto

Desde ontem (domingo) eu tenho notado que o site está com um comportamento bastante instável. O acesso está mais lento do que de costume, mas o principal problema que eu tenho observado são erros arbitrários no momento da publicação de conteúdo.

Ontem a noite fui postar uma resposta e o site simplesmente exibiu uma mensagem de erro (não salvei a imagem). Tentei algumas vezes, julguei que era porque tinha bastante código no corpo da resposta. A solução final foi publicar a resposta sem o código e depois editá-la para incluir o código (em três tentativas).

Hoje, o mesmo me aconteceu com a publicação de comentários (dos mais diversos, sem uma clara indicação de o problema ser devido a existência de links ou ao tamanho do texto).

O que ocorre é, ao clicar em "Adicionar Comentário", o processamento leva quase 20 segundos, e então o comentário não é adicionado e o site exibe a seguinte mensagem em uma caixa vermelha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso só está ocorrendo comigo? Alguém sabe de alguma atualização em andamento ou algo que possa estar interferindo no comportamento padrão do site (que nunca foi ruim assim)?

*P.S.: Não sei quais tags usar, posso ter me equivocado.*

EDIT:

Agora há pouco ocorreu também o erro ao tentar votar positivamente em uma questão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei novamente depois, e foi ok.

Comment: Acho que é só contigo, pode ser o seu ISP, eu me lembro que uma vez apenas em uma região de são paulo, vários sites ficaram inacessíveis e outros ficaram lentos, conversei por Skype com um colega que mora no norte do país e ele conseguiu acessar todos sites que para mim acusava off-line. Mas é só uma suposição.

Comment: Bom, é uma boa suposição @GuilhermeNascimento. Ainda assim, eu não estou observando esse problema em nenhum dos outros sites que acesso, só no SOPT. Mesmo o Meta está funcionando melhor. :)

Comment: Adicionei a imagem com o erro, pois ele acabou de acontecer novamente no site principal [nesta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67053/programa-simples-com-consumo-de-mem%C3%B3ria-acima-de-500mb).

Comment: Então Luiz, mas está é a situação do ISP, não caiu o SOpt, o que caiu foi algo na "cadeia" que acessa a "rede" do pt.stackoverflow.com, que não é a mesma do meta (eu acho). Um teste que você pode fazer é usar o "tracert", mas antes do tracert abra o console e coloque na aba rede, tente fazer uma ação que cause o problema e com isto você poderá ver qual endereço caiu exatamente (pois as vezes não é o pt.stackoverflow.com que está com problemas), tendo o endereço em mãos faça o `tracert` ou `traceroute`, mas acredito ser o pt.stackoverflow.com mesmo...

Comment: ...Acredito que você tenha mais experiencia do que eu na área da informática e que você conheça ambos comando. Tendo o resultado você pode ver se na rota "caiu" um endereço do seu ISP ou do servidor do stackexchange.

Comment: Tenho notado a mesma coisa, e desde o final da semana passada, quinta ou sexta-feira. Hoje esteve especialmente ruim.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Obrigado pelas dicas. Vou tentar fazer. A dificuldade é que o problema não ocorre facilmente. A lentidão está o tempo todo, mas o erro ocorre realmente de forma arbitrária. Já tentei reproduzir, e não consigo facilmente.

Comment: Também observei o problema, já tem um tempo, e estranho que ainda não tive problema no SOen, só no SOpt. Não sei se é o ISP, pois tanto aqui em casa quanto no trabalho está ruim e são provedores diferentes.

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema e não acho que seja com meu ISP. Desde sábado não consigo inserir imagens em publicações. O site está quase inutilizável, chega a demorar minutos para carregar uma página e esporadicamente dá erro ao inserir conteúdo. Nenhum outro site da rede Stack está apresentando o mesmo comportamento. Vim até aqui reportar isso e vi que não sou o único.

Comment: Para mim está respondendo rápido e não apresentou erros, estes dias limpei o cache, será que pode ser algum conflito com versões cacheadas de páginas/scripts do pt.stackoverflow? Poderia tentar abrir o navegador em modo anonimo?

Comment: Aqui está a funcionar direitinho, se bem que eu não tenho feito comentários nem respondido a perguntas...

Comment: Hoje parece ter voltado ao normal. Alguém ainda está vendo erros, ou sentindo o site lento?

Comment: É verdade @bfavaretto, pra mim também parece que voltou ao normal.

Answer (score 3):

Eu estava enfrentando lentidão desde sábado. Percebi que quando acesso pelo Android no meu smartphone não há lentidão, mesmo estando na mesma rede do PC onde o site fica lento. Então comecei a pensar no que poderia influenciar além do sistema operacional e lembrei que no meu Android, o DNS padrão para conexões é o do Google (8.8.8.8).

Então configurei a conexão de rede do PC com o DNS do Google e senti uma melhora, embora ainda não esteja tão rápido quanto o StackOverflow inglês. Testei também com o [OpenDns](https://www.opendns.com/) e também está melhor que o meu DNS padrão. Seguem configurações:

Google DNS:

```
Servidor primário: 8.8.8.8
Servidor secundário: 8.8.4.4
```

OpenDNS:

```
Servidor primário: 208.67.222.222
Servidor secundário: 208.67.220.220
```

Comment: Obrigado por compartilhar essas observações. Vou fazer uma tentativa depois. :)